# Не удаётся сохранить данные в БД

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, telegram, бот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так, как лучше перестроить функцию ниже: при вызове функции данные в БД не добавляются, ошибка не возникает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
def db_table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_surname: str, username: str, user_first_name: str):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE (user_id IS ? )', (user_id, ))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username, user_first_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username, user_first_name));
    return 'Ваши данные сохранены.'
    if row is not None:
        return 'Вы уже зарегистрированы.'
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Какой результат Select?
2. Строку `return 'Ваши данные сохранены.'` должна быть в блоке if. Следовательно...
3. ... выделенный блок исполняться никогда не будет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]